# scroll to animate selected anchor in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple JS function that's animate page scroll to selected anchor by id

all anchor in my page have different offset value and position
tip: I user masonry effect
 but does not work correctly

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid) {
    var aTag = $("a[id='" + aid + "']");
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: aTag.position().top  }, 'slow');
}
```

Comment: "does not work correctly" - what does it do?

Comment: Replace the _position_ with _offset_.

Answer (score 0):

You should use offset instead of position().

But I know by experience that Masonry by default doesn't use position absolute & top, left but it uses a css3-transform instead. And this means that .left and .top will output 0 instead of the css3-transform-value.